# How to disable special characters on textboxes?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:TextBox ID="CommentBox" runat="server" TextMode="multiLine" CssClass="commentTbx" onKeyDown="limitText(this,200);" onKeyUp="limitText(this,200);valid(this);"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;

 function valid(f) {
!(/^[A-zÑñ0-9-\s]*$/i).test(f.value)?f.value = f.value.replace(/[^A-zÑñ0-9-\s]/ig,''):null;
}
```

> Hi above is my javascript function, but i want to allow commas, space and fullstop ONLY! How is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function check(e) {
var keynum
var keychar
var numcheck
// For Internet Explorer
if (window.event)
{
keynum = e.keyCode
}
// For Netscape/Firefox/Opera
else if (e.which)
{
keynum = e.which
}
keychar = String.fromCharCode(keynum)
//List of special characters you want to restrict
if (keychar == "'" || keychar == "`")
{

return false;
}
else {
return true;
}
}
</script>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" onkeypress="return check(event)" ></asp:TextBox>
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Use a [Regular Expression Validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator.aspx).

The advantage for using the ASP .NET validation control is that it will be validated both client side and server side.

As for the regular expression, using something like `[\w\s\.\,]+` should work. But you might need to check the expression.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
textBox = document.getElementById("textbox");
text = textBox.value;
text = text.replace(/[\\!"£$%^&\-\)\(*+_={};:'@#~¦\/<>\""\?|`¬\]\[]/g,'');
textBox.value = text;
```